# Fragment-Activity communication

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have a `fragment` inside a `viewPager` which i am inflating inside an activity. I also have a `tabLayout` with some `tab` items such that when each item is clicked, the fragment is toggled inside the `viewPager.`

My question is this, how do i establish a fragment-activity communication such that the fragment views would be made available to the activity?

I have seen quite some reviews about this but it did not work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an interface in the fragment class and implement that in the activity

**Tutorial:**
http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/

**Official documentation:**

> To allow a Fragment to communicate up to its Activity, you can define
>   an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the
>   Activity. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during
>   its onAttach() lifecycle method and can then call the Interface
>   methods in order to communicate with the Activity.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating